# Merging only certain changes from one git branch to another

Tags: git, git-tower

Say I have a git repository with two branches - `main` and `custom`. Say that I'm working in `custom` and I make two changes to the file `print.php`:

```
/* begin custom only change */
echo "I'm only printed in the custom branch version";
/* end custom only change */

echo "I want this printed in both branches";
```

Say also that meanwhile, I've pulled a new `main` branch copy, and it has the following change to `print.php`:

```
echo "This should also be printed in both branches";
```

What should I do -- either with the command-line or with a git program like Tower (or even suggestions for making a custom script) -- in order to have the following resulting files?

**print.php in main branch**

```
...
echo "I want this printed in both branches";
echo "This should also be printed in both branches";
...
```

**print.php in custom branch**

```
...
/* begin custom only change */
echo "I'm only printed in the custom branch version";
/* end custom only change */

echo "I want this printed in both branches";
echo "This should also be printed in both branches";
...
```

Obviously the order of the `echo "I want this..."` and `echo "This should also..."` is not something that Git can figure out, so there's going to be some manual decision-making here. But I want to know how to do it in the most "Git" way possible and involving the least number of error messages from a program like Tower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way I understand it, you have 2 changes in `custom`, only one of which needs to be merged into `main`, and one change in `main` that needs to be merged into `custom`.  You can solve your issue this way:

- rewind custom to before the 2 changes
- add the one change to `custom` that you will want to merge into `main`
- stash the second change
- merge the one commit from `custom` into `main`, resolving merge conflicts
- merge the changes from `main` into `custom`
- pop the stashed change in `custom`, and commit it

If you've already committed the 2 changes in custom, you'll need to first do `git reset --soft [hash-of-the-commit-before-new-changes]` (you can find the hash for the correct commit with `git log`).  Otherwise, just proceed as below.

You can do line by line commits in interactive git add mode:

```
git add -p print.php
```

In this mode, stage this change first, by itself:

```
echo "I want this printed in both branches";
```

(Once in interactive mode, if you hit "s" git will attempt to split commit hunks into smaller hunks for you.  "y" will stage a hunk for commit, "n" will skip it.  If "s" doesn't work it's magic, hit "e" and manually edit the hunk.  [More info](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging#Staging-Patches))

Once that's staged,

```
git commit
git stash            # stash unstaged, uncommitted change in custom for later
```

Then,

```
git checkout main    # get in main branch
git merge custom     # merge custom, you'll probably get a merge conflict
```

If/when you get a merge conflict:

```
git mergetool
```

I am able to tell git to keep lines from both versions of the file and choose either left or right to appear first in the file.

```
git commit           # commit this change to main
git checkout custom  # get in custom branch
git merge main       # merge main
```

Then,

```
git stash pop        # pop that other change to custom out of the stash
git add print.php    # stage it for commit
git commit           # commit that second change to custom
```

It's ugly... but it works.

Comment: "merge the one commit from custom into main" Won't git complain that custom is behind main and has to pull before merging? Or is it okay because they're different branches?

Comment: I just tried creating your scenario, and did not get that complaint.  However, I've realized that what I suggested won't exactly work.  I'm updating my answer to something that I've actually demonstrated to myself will work.

Comment: Thanks - haven't checked yet, but this looks more like it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a

```
git checkout -p master -- print.php
```

from you custom branch and you can patch certain parts of your file.

[Read more..](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging#Staging-Patches)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to simply do:

```
git checkout custom
git merge master
```

This actually creates an automatic merge.  I made a repo (with one minor typo) at https://gist.github.com/jordansamuels/8cb8ade97fdaf232d26c .

Comment: @Cupcake Good catch of my alias abuse. Edited.

Comment: this is going to merge the entire master branch into custom, and it seems the user is asking to merge only one file